# Cannot import BaseGameUtils (Eclipse weirdness)

Tags: eclipse, compiler-errors, google-play-services, package-name

I closed Eclipse and then re-opened it and now I've got all kind of issues with BaseGameUtils.

I really don't understand as there were no errors when I closed Eclipse and I've not made any changes to anything.

I've tried cleaning and closing Eclipse and re-opening it again but have had no joy.

I've also tried removing Eclipse/Android SDK and downloading it and installing it again / updating and then importing BaseGameUtils again but I still get the same problem.

I'm simply trying to follow the [Offical Docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init).

Would be really grateful if someone can give me some clue as to how I may fix this as my project is currently useless with these errors!

This is the error I get in my BaseGameUtils:

[image]

Any suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have absolutely **no idea why this occurred in the first place** (I'm guessing Eclipse is just a bit odd), however the reason, after re-installing Eclipse/Android-IDE that I was getting errors when importing BaseGameUtils was because I also then needed to go into it's properties and re-link it to the **google-play-services_lib**.

Like so:

[image]

Once I linked that the errors disappeared and I was also able to re-import my project without errors.

Hope this helps if anyone has similar issues in the future

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have your Source folder set to `src` but the code source folder is actually using `src/main`.

Open the Properties for the project and select 'Java Build Path'. Choose the 'Source' tab. Remove the xxxx/src source folder and add xxxx/src/main.

Comment: Hi @greg-449 - many thanks for this, I did get rid of the red 'x' next to BaseGameUtils, but I then had a red '?' in my library section of my main poroject (where I add BaseGameUtils) and the errors in my main project are still there.  Why would that have changed in my project when all I did was exit and re-open Eclipse?  Any other suggestions?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look in the Problems view to see what the errors are

Comment: OK @greg-449 I've remove the Android SDK and re-installed it, loaded all updates and attempted to again follow the official docs: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init to import BaseGameUtils but as soon as I import it I get the same problem as outlined in my question above.  I have no idea.  Like I said, all I did was close Eclipse and re-open it.  There were no problems before.  If you have an other ideas I would be really grateful!! Cheers!